# mySQL query adding conditions when select count

Tags: php, mysql

I have database which books and users, user table have book_ids . What I want is to get the count of users belongs to each book_id, but except one book_id all the other book_ids  I want to exclude emails with 4 domains when count users. How can I do this.

```
SELECT count(id) as user_count ,book_id as booksFROM users  WHERE auth= 5 AND ( disabled=0 OR  disabled IS NULL )AND (valid_to >= NOW() OR valid_to IS NULL ) 
 AND ( email NOT LIKE \"%domain.com\" AND email NOT LIKE \"%abc.co\" AND book_id != 66 ) GROUP BY book_id
```

above is my query. this only return all count of users for the book_id except 66, but I want count for book_id 66 as well but without email check. please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue with the logic you used with the `OR` :

```
SELECT count(id) as user_count, book_id as books
 FROM users
  WHERE auth = 5
    AND (disabled = 0 OR disabled IS NULL)
    AND (valid_to >= NOW() OR valid_to IS NULL)
    AND ((email NOT LIKE "%domain.com\" AND email NOT LIKE "%abc.co\") OR book_id = 66)
GROUP BY book_id
```

Comment: ((email NOT LIKE "%domain.com\" AND email NOT LIKE "%abc.co\") this check is only need book_id != 66 , if book_id = 66 email check no need, is this work with this ?

Comment: Yes @tharuerera